# Write file with UTF-8

Tags: java, android, file, utf-8

I'm trying to write a file with utf-8 encoding.
This file I would like to see on PC in Excel
I've looked at enough examples of implementing this code. But I did not achieve the desired results.
My code:

```
    String baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = etName.getText().toString() + ".csv";
    String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
    File sdCardFile = new File(filePath);

    String DATE = "01.04.2017 - 30.04.2017";
    String NEW_LINE = "\n";
    String NEW_CELL = ";";
    String HEADER = "Место;" +
            "Фамилия ИО;" +
            "Цикл ТО-1;" +
            "Культурное состояние л-ва;" +
            "Посещение тех.занятий;" +
            "Расшифровка лент;" +
            "Охрана труда;" +
            "Отказы";

BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sdCardFile), "UTF-8"));
        bufferedWriter.write(DATE);
        bufferedWriter.write(NEW_LINE);
        bufferedWriter.write(HEADER);
        for(int i = 0; i < machinists.size(); i ++){
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_LINE);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(i+1));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(machinists.get(i).getLastName());
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getTo()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getCultureState()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getTechnicalSessions()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getTapeTranscript()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getOt()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(machinists.get(i).getPoints().getFault()));
            bufferedWriter.write(NEW_CELL);
        }
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
```

But I see this.

[image: screenshot excel csv]

Why?

Comment: I also tried this code: BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sdCardFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()));

Comment: Are you sure that Excel is interpreting it as an UTF-8 file, or is it reading it as if it is in a different character encoding?

Comment: Do not use the literal "UTF-8". Use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Comment: @Jesper No. I'm not sure about that. I'm doing this for the first time. But if you re-save it in NotePad with UTF-8 encoding, Excel displays the file, the way I want it.

Comment: @Michael StandardCharsets.UTF_8 required API level 19. Min API level is 16 ((((

Comment: @niklas1987 Annoying. That's been in Java since 1.4. Try the literal "UTF8" without the dash.

Comment: @niklas1987, Can you share an example output file (the current output)?

Comment: @Michael No. This not help me (((((

Comment: @ Doron Yakovlev-Golani http://dropmefiles.com/FAffZ

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem!

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sdCardFile);
        os.write(0xef);<-!!!!!!!!
        os.write(0xbb);<-!!!!!!!!
        os.write(0xbf);<-!!!!!!!!
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os), ';');
writer.writeNext(HEADER);
...
writer.writeNext('something data');
writer.close();
```

Comment: For excel to recognize a CSV file as UTF-8, you need to add the Byte order mark. This is a 3 byte sequence; 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. This is done in this code but not in your first one.

Comment: You saved my days!

Comment: how can save in cp1256?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help, but maybe formatting the string to UTF-8 this way can help:

```
bufferedWriter.write(new String(machinists.get(i).getLastName().getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

And similarly for the headers.

**Edit:**

Another thing you can try is to add `"` for all the values and `,` as the delimiter (csv stands for "comma separated values" after all):

```
"1","Аркаев","10","7","6","5","0","6",
```

Comment: No. This not help me ((

Comment: bufferedWriter.write("\"" +machinists.get(i).getLastName() + "\"," ); bufferedWriter.write("\"" + new String(HEADER.getBytes(), "UTF-8") + "\","); doesn't help me ((((

Comment: Maybe the problem is with how you open the file?

Comment: @ Doron Yakovlev-Golani just double click.

Comment: I don't have Excel installed - I see Cyrilic letters when I open the file in Numbers (Apple's version of Excel). Anyway, the text is not formatted as CSV as you are using the wrong delimiter. If I were you, I'd fix that first and then make sure I am importing the file properly (maybe instead of double clicking it, you should try to manually import from within - I've seen changes in the behavior in the past between the two methods).