# FileOutputStream set encoding with write byte to file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

i have a csv file that i save it with utf-8 encoding like below:
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921593/5456789)

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
       
/*utf-8 setting*/
fileOut.write(0xef);
fileOut.write(0xbb);
fileOut.write(0xbf);

 /*append another string*/
 PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileOut);
 printWriter.write(...);
```

i write string to file and it work correctly with `UTF-8` encodeing.

my question is :

1. anyone know what is this bytes?
2. how can change it to another encoding like `cp1256`?
3. is a list that provide all encoding for that?

**UPDATE**:
assume that i save huge string data that create in pagination and i can not store this size of data in one time.

thanks

Comment: That's an UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), nature's cruellest mistake. You can't change the encoding with that.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use the FileUtils from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)?
This will make your life much easier. ;-)

And, If you want to covert the content, have a look here: [Encoding conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: as i have huge data for save in csv file, i need save it per data pagination. so FileUtils.write( file,"data",Charset) is not help me. i edit question

Comment: ok i use 4th parameter of `FileUtils.write` and it help me. thank you i plus this answer